# GeoServer WFS service not returning all attributes

Tags: geoserver

I have published a layer which contains around 76 columns(Attributes). But when i make a WFS service call its not returning all the attributes(Columns) one is getting missed whose name is "ID". I am using oracle Spatial 11G DB which contains the map data. Am i missing something? All the other things are working fine like WMS service.

Comment: Id is a reserved word in gml

Comment: @iant The url was returning in JSON format not in GML

Comment: I think @iant 's comment applies to formats other than gml.  Its reasonable that Id is reserved.  Is it possible to change the name of the column in the source data and republish the layer?  Perhaps increase the logging verbosity when making a request and see if you can find the SQL that is getting executed or if there are messages regarding that field.  When you preview the layer through the admin app, does the field show up in the details grid below the map?

Comment: I know that the question is 1 year old, but may be useful: the attribute is not returned even if the attribute name **contains** the 'ID' keyword (e.g. id_spec is not returned in attributes)

Answer (score -1):

In my own experience with Geoserver 2.6.1 , I've found when requesting attributes by name the casing must be matched to the attribute name that appears on the *Feature Type Details* of the *Edit Layer* page in the admin webapp.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12218004)

Comment: @Nanhydrin : I disagree, attribute casing is exactly what has caused the OP's problem in my own experience.  I wasn't seeking clarification -- I was offering a solution.  I'll rephrase to be more answer-like.

Comment: phrasing is everything. The way you had it worded originally it was a comment, but now it reads more like an answer.

Comment: I was not using any filter since i wanted everything to be fetched.